# Does BEM force you to create unnecessary elements?

Tags: html, css, bem

```
<header>
  <a href="#"><img src="kitty.jpg" /></a>
  ...
</header>
```

For example, I have this sitting in the header, and it doesn't depend on the `header` block. In order to make it BEM-friendly, I lean towards doing this:

```
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="#" class="logo__link"><img src="kitty.jpg" class="logo__img" /></a>
  </div>
  ...
</header>
```

Is this the correct way to approach BEM?

Answer (score 3):

By "it doesn't depend on the `header` block" I assume you mean that you reuse this logo-esque structure elsewhere. By definition, then, it is a block, since it has ["no dependency on other blocks/elements on a page"](http://getbem.com/naming/).

Therefore, if my interpretation of your question is correct, you should be able to give your anchor tag a class of `logo` and the image within `logo__img`; the wrapper `div.logo` is unnecessary.

To answer the title question, no, BEM shouldn't really force your much HTML in any way. It's primarily a CSS methodology, and you can define blocks and elements on any DOM node that accepts class names.

Comment: I was confused because there's definitely a bit of prejudice in the term "block". An anchor tag doesn't feel right to be called a block, but I guess it's totally fine in BEM.